# How to type an array to be sure that all posisble values are from an specific dict?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking some way to type the testArray to ensure that only keys from the dict example can be set in the array.

```
enum example {
    key1 = 'A',
    key2 = 2,
    key3 = '3',
};

const testArray: ?? = [example.key1, example.key2]; // Valid
const testArray: ?? = [example.key1, 'other']; // Invalid
```

I want ensure that only keys of example dict can be added to the testArray this way.

Comment: Your question reads slightly ambiguously... What would be in the final array? `['key1', 'key2']` or `['A', 'B']`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
let example = {
  key1: 'A',
  key2: 2,
  key3: '3',
} as const;

type ExampleValueArray = typeof example[keyof typeof example][]

const testArray: ExampleValueArray = [example.key1, example.key2]; // Valid
const testArray2: ExampleValueArray = [example.key1, 'other']; // Invalid
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=74&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAGwpgLgBGAeCGBbADuKBeKBvYUoGswBPARgC4oByAQUoBpcDiAmC5hvQogZgsu-rAAvlHgBnKAGMA9gDsxEANzBgEIsjBQAoghTgAavBABXMNQBO5%20EQxQ1G6QDMYu1GADaXJ3fVhvcJDcAXXcglRl5aAgwBQsrIgodQIMjUzjrW3cAvTAAOi4SOhdkvK5mIMUoAHoqqEMQAEsAE2AIhTsYiHSiVm1XFJMzSwzMLP7S4kKqaQgACzBzSgrq2oBJWQA3I2agA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want that only the keys present in example to be present in an array you can use this

```
let example = {
  key1: 'A',
  key2: B,
  key3: '3',
};

export const testArray: (keyof typeof example)[];
```

Note that this will allow for multiple entries for `key1`, `key2`, etc.

If you want the values then you can use this

```
let example = {
  key1: 'A',
  key2: 'B',
  key3: '3',
} as const;

const a: ((typeof example)[keyof typeof example])[];
```

Comment: The problem here is that I don't want to have `['key1']` I want to have: `[example.key1]`